# Java Spring Resource Server seems to check JWT token on response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a @EnableResourceServer which checks a JWT on requests.
This JWT has a 30 seconds TTL, it is accepted by my REST API.
But sometimes the process takes more than 30 seconds before the response is sent.

Even if my app returns a 200 response code, Spring replaces it with a 401, meaning my JWT has expired.

I think it's a bad behavior, JWT should not been checked on response.
Did someone experience the same issue and know how to avoid it ?

I use Spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE, spring-security-oauth2 2.2.1.RELEASE, spring-security-jwt 1.0.9.RELEASE.

My class :

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@Profile("security")
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/pay/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

and I'm using the property :

```
   security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri=
```

Here a log proving the call is made twice :

```
2018-03-27T15:07:48.801-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2018-03-27 19:07:48.800 DEBUG [accueil-transfert,c0baad95368697cd,c0baad95368697cd,true] 15 --- [io-8080-exec-10] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@822a1a7a: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Not granted any authorities

...

2018-03-27T15:08:39.130-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2018-03-27 19:08:39.129 DEBUG [accueil-transfert,c0baad95368697cd,c0baad95368697cd,true] 15 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="Access token expired: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiAiUElTR...
```

The request is stored in a completableFuture in my RestController:

```
    @PostMapping("/myUrl")
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<CorpsReponseDto>> effectue(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders enteteRequete,
            @Valid @RequestBody CorpsRequeteDto corpsRequete, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<CorpsReponseDto>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        ...
        return future;
}
```

And completed in a @Service class :

```
future.complete(new ResponseEntity<>(reponseDto, httpStatus));
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The call is not made twice for one request, because the logs are from different threads: `[io-8080-exec-10]` and `[nio-8080-exec-1]` Normally one request is only bound to one thread.

Comment: Could it be because we're handling the request with a 'CompletableFuture' before sending the response ? To be asynchronous. So the thread processing the request is not the same as the one processing the response.

Comment: Thanks, it seems we are on the good way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680072/why-filter-chain-is-called-twice-for-an-asynchronous-endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is that the 'filterChain' is called once for REQUEST type (used for HTTP request reception) and once for Async type (the one used in CompletableFuture on response process).

There is one property to set to avoid the Async chain :

```
security.filter-dispatcher-types=REQUEST, ERROR
```

(seen on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/736)

Answer (score 0):

I have understood you question clearly what is the process take more than 30s, but 
The benefits of JWT Token store is the Resource Server no need to check in the Authorization Server when the RestAPI Consume calling the Resource Endpoint, because the resource can modify itself by using the public key.

By @EnableResourceServer and auto configuration provided in application.properties for security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri.

Comment: Could you provide the details? what did you mean response more than 30s? You calling the other restapi from resource server?

Comment: It's the time between the acceptation of the request and the response sending. My app depends on other apps and I don't have control on them. My app is a resource server and works well to check JWT signature on the request. But it seems to check it also on response send.

Comment: if the requested token got and passed from your resource server before the token expired it should be ok, because spring security oauth filter chain before you try to access the resource endpoint it is not about checking after other api response. Because your token already passed.

Comment: Yes, indeed, for the request, it works fine. But I'm talking about the response. Forget about other APIs. The fact is : if the response is sent after token expiration, Spring Security sends a 401 HTTP response, even if my app would send a 200. That's why I think there is a bug in Spring Security.